# How can I resolve interface method and base class method name conflict in C++ Builder?

Tags: c++, c++builder, multiple-inheritance

I have the following abstract base class, SettingsInterface, that I use as an interface:

```
class SettingsInterface
{
public:
    virtual void Refresh()      = 0;
    virtual void Update()       = 0;
    virtual void OnConnect()    = 0;
    virtual void OnDisconnect() = 0;
};
```

I'm trying to implement this interface in my class below, which inherits from TFrame. TFrame inherits from another class that also has a virtual method called Update.

```
class DebugSettingsFrame : public TFrame, public SettingsInterface
{
      //a bunch of IDE-managed components - left out for brevity
public:
     virtual void Refresh();
     virtual void Update();
     virtual void OnConnect();
     virtual void OnDisconnect();    
};
```

When I compile this, I get the error virtual function DebugSettingsFrame::Update() conflicts with base class 'TWinControl'. 
I'm stomped on this. How can I resolve this without changing my interface's method definition, Update, to something else?

**Edit - Follow-up:**

So C++ doesn't have a construct similar to C# where you can explicitly implement interface methods that have the same definition?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Try something like (from the code I can't say exactly):

DebugSettingsFrame::TFrame::Update();

:: is the scope resolution operator.  You should be able to specify precisely which version of the function you are calling.

However, note that this is a symptom of a design that may be getting too complex.

Comment: Really?  Did the C++ spec change?  I used to teach C++ and one of my examples was how to deal with multiply inheriting from two classes where each class had a variable with the same name.  The only way to deal with it was the scope resolution operator.

Comment: You're not wrong about that, but in this case the problem is that his version of `Update` is a pure virtual function.  This will conflict with `TFrame::Update`, which is not pure.  Will edit my answer to clarify this.